# Text over semi-transparent background

Tags: xaml, transparency

This must be so simple but I can't do it: if I put a textblock in a container and make the container's opacity < 1, the text inherits that opacity, no matter whether I try to override it in the textblock.  How can I keep the text 100% opacity while in a semii-transparent container?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Border Background="red" Opacity="0.5">
        <TextBlock Text="TextBlok" Opacity="1"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just use the a color value in stead of an opacity to make it transparant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Will this do the trick?

```
<Border Background="#80FF0000">
    <TextBlock Text="TextBlok"/>
</Border>
```

Setting the background to be transparent, not the whole Border element...

Answer (score 3):

Just use the a color value in stead of an opacity to make it transparant.

The Color property can be formed out of 4 parameters being :

1. Transparancy
2. Red
3. Green
4. Blue

All of them ranging from 0-255

A half transparant blue would be : (128,0,0,255)
Translated into XAML (Hexidecimal) : #800000FF

This color you can use in any colorbrush.

So else has already an example how to implementate it in your code I just see.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the same answer as Arjan above, but he was first so gets the tick. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5"></SolidColorBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <TextBlock Text="Hallo there"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```