# Different opacity for the contained control

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 Application.

I have one stackpanel control that hosts some other controls. I want to set some opacity for the stackpanel and a different opacity for the contained controls. How can I do this? I tried:

```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="135" Width="450" Name="StackPanel1" Background="Gray" Opacity="0.1">
         <TextBlock Name="gameStatus" TextAlignment="Center" Width="450" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="22" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" Text="{Binding Status}" Opacity="1"/>
   <Stackpanel/>
```

But the contained textblock always inherits the opacity of the stackpanel...

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760501/xaml-text-over-semi-transparent-background

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've discovered, **Opacity** (like other dependency proeprties) is inherited by child elements. To work round this, simply set an alpha value in the **Background** color of your parent element instead of using the **Opacity**.

In your example, the color Gray is #808080, so to give it an opacity of 0.1, simply set: `Background="#19808080"` and remove the **Opacity** property.